# Возникает NullPointerException при работе с ImageView

Tags: android, исключения

Код такой. На  `icnCamera.setVisibility(View.GONE);` вываливается NullPointerException. Всё же определено, что не так?

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
...
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_news_list, container, false);

        ImageView icnCamera = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iconCamera);
        ImageView icnNews = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iconNews);
        icnCamera.setVisibility(View.GONE);
...
}
```

fragment_news_list.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_news"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

В адаптере ресайклера в newscard_row.xml 2 `ImageView` :

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/iconCamera"
        android:src="@drawable/iconscamera"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:baselineAlignBottom="false" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/iconNews"
        android:src="@drawable/iconsnews"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Comment: вы обращаетесь к разметке фрагмента, чтобы найти ImageView, но там кроме RecyclerView ничего нет. Ваш ImageView находится в айтеме списка и доступ к нему нельзя получить таким способом, как вы пытаетесь

Comment: а как тогда можно?

Comment: с этими картинками нужно работать через адаптер списка. Из вашего вопроса не понятно, что именно вы хотите с ними делать.

Comment: они будут иконками, обозначающими тематику каждого айтема в ресайклере. В зависимости от темы будет проставляться видимость иконки.

Comment: эту видимость вам нужно указывать в методе `onBindViewHolder()` адаптера

Comment: спасибо, попробую!